# how to use reflection package to create an object from a classpath

Tags: java, reflection

I want to create an object I know only its classpath
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _"I know only its classpath?"_ Exactly what information do you have to work with? +1 to @BalusC's comment as well.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "classpath"? The full qualified classname in a `java.lang.String` or the classpath location in a `java.net.URL` (as obtained by `ClassLoader#getResource()`) or an absolute file path in a `java.io.File`?

Comment: Classpath? If you mean something along the lines "org.mycompany.FirstClass" than you're good to go! This kind of string is called Fully Qualified Name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the full qualified classname in a `String`, use [`Class#forName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) and [`Class#newInstance()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29).

```
Object o = Class.forName("com.example.Foo").newInstance();
```

This however requires the class to be already present in the classpath and have a (implicit) default constructor.

If it is not, and you have the class' location in an [`URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), then use [`URLClassLoader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) and pass it to another [`Class#forName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) method which accepts it as an argument.

```
URL url = getItSomehow();
URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { url });
Object o = Class.forName("com.example.Foo", true, classLoader).newInstance();
```

Or, if you have it in a [`File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) instead, then convert it to `URL` first:

```
File file = getItSomehow();
URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
// Continue with URLClassLoader.
```

Comment: OK, but what if I want to call any method belongs to the class, that I know its path or qualified name

Comment: That's a different question, so here's just a tutorial link instead of an answer: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html If you stucks, press `Ask Question` button on right top. Don't forget to include detail about the particular step you're stucking with, preferably along with a small code snippet which reproduces exactly your problem. Be careful with choosing and using the right terms. The term "classpath" was apparently not what you thought it was :)

Comment: OK, but I want to clarify that in my project I have 3 packages with 3 classes I want in 4th package and 4th class to instantiate an object of one of the three classes in the 3 packages according to input from the user.

Comment: Yes, I already guessed something like that. The 1st point of my answer is then applicable.

Comment: but I still have to check if the class 'o'  is one of the three classes or in other words repeat the code 3 times for the three classes.. I used reflection to get an optimal solution for this case

Comment: Just use `instanceof` and then cast it, or, better, let them implement a common interface as per the abstract factory pattern. If you stucks, press `Ask Question` in right top since that's out of the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean this ?

```
Class c = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
```